# i ran the following command on docker it shows the folllowing error how to get rid of this?

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, compiling, git

I ran the following command on docker and got the error below. How can I fix this?

```
FROM compiler-common AS compi
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=nonintera

RUN apt-get install -y --no-i
 git-core \
 checkinstall \
 g++ \
 make \
 tar \
 curl \
 wget \
 build-essential \
 cmake \
 autotools-dev \
 automake \
 autogen \
 ca-certificates
RUN cd ~ \
&& git clone --single-branch 
&& cd libgeotiff \
&& ./autogen.sh \
&& ./configure \
&& make dist \
&& tar xvzf libgeotiff*.tar.g
&& cd libgeotiff* \
&& mkdir build_autoconf \
&& cd build_autoconf \
&& CFLAGS="-Wall -Wextra -Wer
&& make -j3 \
&& make check \
&& cd .. \
&& mkdir build_cmake \
&& cd build_cmake \
&& cd ../.. \
&& make -j3 \
&& apt --fix-broken install \
```

Error:

```
Cloning into 'libgeotiff'...
/bin/sh: 1: ./autogen.sh: not found
ERROR: Service 'map' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c cd ~ && git clone --single-branch https://github.com/OSGeo/libgeotiff.git --depth 1 && cd libgeotiff && ./autogen.sh && ./configure && make dist && tar xvzf libgeotiff*.tar.gz && cd libgeotiff* && mkdir build_autoconf && cd build_autoconf && CFLAGS="-Wall -Wextra -Werror" ../configure && make -j3 && make check && cd .. && mkdir build_cmake && cd build_cmake && cd ../.. && make -j3 && apt --fix-broken install FROM ubuntu:20.04 AS final-base' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Comment: Do you have this missing file? autogen.sh: not found

Comment: Is the `compiler-common` image based on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You're in the wrong directory. You are cloning this repository: https://github.com/OSGeo/libgeotiff/tree/master/libgeotiff. As you can see in your log, it is being cloned into `~/libgeotiff`, the contents of which are:

```
$ ls libgeotiff/
geotiff  libgeotiff  README.md
```

Your `autoconf.sh` file, however, is in a *subdirectory* of `~/libgeotiff` called `libgeotiff`:

```
$ ls libgeotiff/libgeotiff/*sh
libgeotiff/libgeotiff/autogen.sh  libgeotiff/libgeotiff/install-sh
```

So you need to change your `cd` command to:

```
cd libgeotiff/libgeotiff && 
./autogen.sh && 
./configure
```